# Typescript error - After installing flex-layout in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular2-directives, angular-flex-layout

I installed flex layout using `"npm install @angular/flex-layout"`.

After installation, I get this typescript error message.

> "node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member
>   'Renderer2'." "node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported
>   member 'InjectionToken'."

I am using `Angular Core: 2.4.10` version and
`Node: 7.5.0 version.`

**Screenshot**:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

The latest version "@angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.8" is not supported in angular 2.4.10. I installed **@angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.5** and it worked. Please refer the change log here https://github.com/angular/flex-layout-builds/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md